# Visualizing and exploring survey data. What is possible using hihgcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I am new to highcharts, so i am trying to create a picture of what is possible and what is not.
I have been playing around with the full editor, and is able to produce and embed graphs.

However..

I have access to quite a few large datasets from a survey. I want the user to be able to explore the data on their own.
For example, if i have the categories Gender, Favorite color, Home town, Age. Is it possible for the user to filter the data to find how many men with favorite color blue, living in London is aged 32?

I used flourish to produce this result: https://public.flourish.studio/visualisation/12973431/

Flourish use a boubble per data point. I'm envisioning more like a bar graph counting strings a numbers.

I have tried uploading a dataset with "strings" (yes,no, male, female), but the highcharts full editor give an error message.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Highcharts does not provide this kind of tool out of the box, but you can use the Highcharts API to create a chart that allows users to filter data based on their selections. To achieve such a chart, you will need to parse your data in a specific way before using them.

Here is a basic idea of using `column.stacking` chart and custom function which sorts data, that you can base on:

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>

<label for="select">Group by:</label>
<select id="select" onchange="seriesUpdate(this.value)">
    <option value="color" selected="selected">Color</option>
        <option value="city">City</option>
        <option value="gender">Gender</option>
</select>
```

Example data:

```
let data = [{
    y: 1,
    gender: 'male',
    city: 'New York',
    color: 'green'
  },
  {
    y: 1,
    gender: 'male',
    city: 'New York',
    color: 'red'
  },
...}
```

JS

```
function sortData(seriesName) {
  let newData = data.map((point) => [point[seriesName], point.y]),

    // When stacking is used, data must be sorted
    sortedData = newData.sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
  return sortedData
}


let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    formatter() {
      let i = this.point.index;
      return 'Gender: ' + data[i].gender + '</br>' + 'Color: ' + data[i].color + '</br>' + 'City: ' + data[i].city
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Color',
    data: sortData('color')
  }]
});

function seriesUpdate(seriesName) {
  chart.series[0].update({
    name: seriesName,
    data: sortData(seriesName)
  })
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xf2dbn3z/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.stacking
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter